# Is a 5 foot square on a battle map 5 sq. ft.?

Tags: battle-map, map-making, d20-modern

I am making a map for a modern day game my DM is running, and I have an architectural image of a floor plan with listed square footage.

For a D20 Modern's 5ft grid, how would I figure out how many squares fit in an area to make it realistic? For instance, I have an area of 241 sq.ft. So how many squares would I fit in there and how would I find this information for other sq.ft.? I'm using GIMP to make the grid, if it matters. Would I just divide the 241 into 5 to find my area?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Each 5' square actually takes up 25 square feet (5' x 5').  So you could divide up the 241/25 to get roughly 10 squares, or you could figure out the original length and width and divide each of those by 5' (and round up I guess).

Comment: Note that if your 241sq.ft. room is roughly square in shape, that's basically a 3x3 grid. That's a tiny room, in DnD terms.

Answer (score 15):

In D20 Modern, a "5-foot square" is a square which measures 5 feet along each side. It has an area of *25 square feet*, not 5 square feet. Look in the game manual on pages 142, under "Movement and Position":

> Using a map grid divided into 1-inch squares also helps. The standard scale equates 1 inch on the tabletop (or one 1-inch square) to 5 feet in the game world.

And from the chart on the same page:

> A human-size creature occupies an area 1 inch (5 feet) across (or one square)

You may also want to look at the sidebar "Using a Grid" on the next page of the manual.

**So, if your room is 241 square feet, that's approximately 10 5-foot squares**, because 241 ÷ 25 is a little more than 9.

As [@Mooing Duck](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4119/mooing-duck) notes, in D20/D&D gameplay, that's a tiny room (because of the rule about a person in combat taking a full square). For the sake of gameplay, you may decide to forgo accuracy and stretch things a little, perhaps making it 5×5 instead of 3×3.

Comment: Or leave it small and force fighting players to deal with the penalties of being crowded in more than one to a square...  That works too.